# window sidebar addPanel not work in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, bookmarks

```
<script>
    function Bookmark() {

        alert(navigator.userAgent);
        if (window.sidebar) { // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
            window.sidebar.addPanel(location.href, document.title, "");
        }
        else if (window.external) { // IE Favorite
            window.external.AddFavorite(location.href, document.title);
        }
        else if (window.opera && window.print) {
            alert("ASAS");
            var e = document.createElement('a');
            e.setAttribute('href', location.href);
            e.setAttribute('title', document.title);
            e.setAttribute('rel', 'sidebar');
            e.click();
        }
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="Bookmark()">Bookmark</a>
```

I has a script to let user click to bookmark the page.  It work ok in IE, but it not work in Firefox24.0 version.  It show me error window.sidebar.addPanel is not a function.  Any one has idea whats go wrong for the above code.  Please help!!!  Brilliant thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addPanel` [was removed from Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=691647) since v. 23. But you can use markup instead:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" title="Stack Overflow" rel="sidebar">Bookmark me</a>
```