# How to allow my Product1 users to bookmark my Product2 link from Product1 web page?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to allow my user to bookmark my external product link by clicking on the button but getting a problem with `window.sidebar.addPanel` and `window.external.AddFavorite` as both are not supported now.

I have a PHP application and looking for the best suitable solutions here.

I am getting

> Uncaught TypeError: window.sidebar.addPanel is not a function

error with following code.

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function AddToBookmark() {
      if (window.sidebar) { // Firefox
        window.sidebar.addPanel('Dottoro help page', 'http://help.dottoro.com', '');
      } else {
        if (window.external && ('AddFavorite' in window.external)) {
          // Internet Explorer
          window.external.AddFavorite('http://help.dottoro.com', 'Dottoro help page');
        } else { // Opera, Google Chrome and Safari
          alert("Your browser doesn't support this example!");
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="AddToBookmark();">Add to Bookmark</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: `window.sidebar.addPanel` was removed in Firefox v23 roughly 10 years ago: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=691647

Comment: Yes, I am looking into any alternative best solution as this is removed. In fact, this is not working Chrome also.  We have 2 products and I want to allow my product 1 users to bookmark Product 2 by clicking some link or button.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19290067/13833218)

> `addPanel` was removed from Firefox since v. 23. But you can use
> markup instead:
>
> ```
> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" title="Stack Overflow" rel="sidebar">Bookmark me</a>
> ```

Hence you can simulate a click on a similar `<a>` tag in your `AddToBookmark()` function as below.

```js
const anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
anchorTag.href = "http://help.dottoro.com"
anchorTag.title= "Dottoro help page";
anchorTag.rel= "sidebar";
anchorTag.click();
```

```html
<body>

  <button onclick="AddToBookmark();">Add to Bookmark</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function AddToBookmark() {
      if (window.sidebar) { // Firefox
        const anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
        anchorTag.href = "http://help.dottoro.com"
        anchorTag.title = "Dottoro help page";
        anchorTag.rel = "sidebar";
        anchorTag.click();
      } else {
        if (window.external && ('AddFavorite' in window.external)) {
          // Internet Explorer
          window.external.AddFavorite('http://help.dottoro.com', 'Dottoro help page');
        } else { // Opera, Google Chrome and Safari
          alert("Your browser doesn't support this example!");
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```